# Using f3write to determine USB Drive size: specific syntax

Tags: usb, mount, hardware-test

I have installed `f3` (fight flash fraud) on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 in order to test my USB stick purchases from the command line. My newest Kingston 16GB successfully passed the `f3probe` test and for practice I want to run `f3write` and `f3read` also, but I'm seeing some oddities and have terminated the tests.

The stick is mounted and Files app identifies it as `/media/jw/2177-E385` so I have attempted to run the command variously as

1. `sudo f3write /media/jw`
2. `sudo f3write /media/jw/`
3. `sudo f3write /media/jw/2177-E385`.

Which is the mount point that I need for this operation? The partition is located at `/dev/sdd1`.

I am seeing some 1.h2w, 2.h2w, etc., written into the /media/jw directory in files, but not into 2177-E385.

What concerns me the most is that, when running `f3write`, the command line shows 908GB free space, the size of my hard drive, not 16GB, the size of my USB stick; I don't want to test the computer's hard drive.

I would appreciate some assistance with the syntax in order to let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: And what does `man f3write` say?

Comment: The f3 man refers to <path> on the assumption that I already know the syntax: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/f3read.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stick is mounted as `/media/jw/2177-E385` then that folder is the one you need to supply to f3write.  So:

```
sudo f3write /media/jw/2177-E385/
```

is the correct command.

You can delete all the other h2w files.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. Can you comment on why the  command line refers to 908GB of free space, the hard drive, instead of the 16GB USB stick? The 16GB is what I've seen in the examples I can find.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why you would see an incorrect quantity here: (1) The device isn't actually mounted.  For example, when you plug a USB stick in it isn't always mounted automatically.  You have to go into Nautilus to trigger the mount. (2) You have the wrong mountpoint.  If, for example, the USB stick is suffers from a system fault that locks the mountpoint, then the OS will create a new mountpoint at `/media/jw/2177-E385-1` (or some such).   Better to check with `df` or `mount` that you have the right mountpoint before performing these kinds of operations.

Comment: I had not tried the combination with the slash at the end of the path, and that worked. It also provided the accurate Free Space - 14.4GB. Also, the df --All command indicated that it was mounted - very useful command.

Comment: Another nice alternative to `df` or `mount ` is **`lsblk`**.